# SQL use nested select in middle of inner join

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Is it possible to use a select in the middle of joining...

I am trying to do the following:

```
FROM 
tblorders o 
INNER JOIN tblunits u on o.id = u.orderid
INNER JOIN ((SELECT
                   ,Min(n.date) as [MinDate]
              from tblNotes n
             Where n.test = 'test') te
INNER JOIN tblnotes n on te.id = n.id
                     and te.[MinDate] = n.AuditinsertTimestamp)
INNER Join tblClient c ON o.ClientId = c.Id
```

Basically in the select in the middle of the query it is selecting only the notes with min date. The problem is I need to do this here because I need from tblOrders to be the first table.......

Suggestions?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? :)

Comment: I am trying to get the select to work in the inner join

Comment: I mean, globally. Describe the whole problem.

Comment: you only have inner joins here. WHy do you care if "because I need from tblOrders to be the first table"?

Comment: INNER JOIN((
SELECT 
n.[RelatedEntityId] 
,MIN(n.[AuditInsertTimestamp]) AS [MinDate]
FROM tblNotes n
WHERE n.[Text] LIKE '<p>The status for the Unit # % has changed from % to OUTTOVENDOR</p>') te
INNER JOIN [dbo].[tblNotes] n ON te.[ID] = n.[Id]
AND te.[MinDate] = n.[AuditInsertTimestamp])

Comment: nevermind its because there is NO group by!!! :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The INNER JOIN failed because you have a leading comma here:

```
,Min(n.date) as [MinDate]
```

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
SELECT ...
FROM tblorders o   
INNER JOIN tblunits u on o.id = u.orderid  
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT id, Min(date) as [MinDate]  
    from tblNotes 
    Where test = 'test'  
    group by id
) te  <-- not sure what JOIN clause to use here, please post schema
INNER JOIN tblnotes n on te.id = n.id  
    and te.[MinDate] = n.AuditinsertTimestamp  
INNER Join tblClient c ON o.ClientId = c.Id
```

Answer (score 3):

You are missing an alias and join condition:

```
FROM 
tblorders o 
INNER JOIN tblunits u on o.id = u.orderid
INNER JOIN ((SELECT Min(n.date) as [MinDate]
              from tblNotes n
             Where n.test = 'test') te
INNER JOIN tblnotes n on te.id = n.id
                     and te.[MinDate] = n.AuditinsertTimestamp)
-- missing
AS z
ON <join conditions haere>
INNER Join tblClient c ON o.ClientId = c.Id
```

Comment: Your derived table is missing a column before the Min()

Answer (score -6):

Yes, you can have a Select in a Join.

Comment: as result from a select query is also a table you can have that selects.